# Error by Groovy plugin in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I get following error when debugging my code in Intellij.
I checked out the place of `agent\gragent.jar` but it does not exist.
I temporarily solve it by deactivating the plugin but i want a proper solution.

**Does anybody know why and how to solve it?**

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error opening zip file: C:\development\tools\IntelliJ IDEA   11.1.2\plugins\Groovy\lib\agent\gragent.jar
agent library failed to init: instrument

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [IDEA 11.1.3](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html), this file is available on my system.

Comment: I have the same version as you but i don't know how it happened. I can't reinstall it(no permission).if i can find this file somewhere i can copy it.

Comment: ftp://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.idea/11/gragent.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can find this file in any other version of Intelij 10 or 11(i did from Intellij 10) Copy it and past it to the IDEA 11.1.3. restart Intellij everything will be OK.